# Header/Footer and isov2 document class

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, iso

I am currently using the **isov2** document class.  I would like for a header/footer to be on every page (it varies from even to odd).  I am using the current code from the fancyhdr package.

```
% Header and Footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\uppercase{ISO/IEEE 11073-10201:2013(E)}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\tiny{\uppercase{Health informatics --- Point-of-care medical device communication}}} % will need to resize later (NOT to tiny)
\fancyhead[LO]{\uppercase{Part 10201: Domain information model}}
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{Copyright \textcopyright $\;$ 2013 ISO/IEEE. All rights reserved.}
%\fancyfoot[CO,RE]{To: Dean A. Smith}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
```

However, I've noticed that both the header and footer only appear on pages before the title page.  They "disappear" after the first few pages.  I have tried removing the options from the document class but that hasn't helped.  I have looked through the iso class PDF as well and can't find a solution.  A MWE is included below.  Thank you.

```
\documentclass[draft,wd,letterpaper]{isov2}
\let\ifpdf\relax 

% Header and Footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\uppercase{ISO/IEEE 11073-10201:2013(E)}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\tiny{\uppercase{Health informatics --- Point-of-care medical device communication}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\uppercase{Part 10201: Domain information model}}
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{Copyright \textcopyright $\;$ 2013 ISO/IEEE. All rights reserved.}
%\fancyfoot[CO,RE]{To: Dean A. Smith}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}


\standard{ISO/IEEE 11073-10201}
\yearofedition{2013}
\languageofedition{(E)}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}     % ToC includes ssclauses and above

\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\clause{Before Title}
Words before Title
\title{Example Document}{}{}

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\clause{Hello}\lipsum
\sclause{Little}\lipsum
\clause{Second}\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides `empty`, the `isov2` class uses three defined page styles: `startpage`, `isotitlehead` and `headings`: the simplest way to activate your headers/footers on every page is to `\let` those styles (or some of them, depending on which pages you want to keep the standard ones) to be your `fancyplain` style using

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@headings\ps@fancyplain
\let\ps@isotitlehead\ps@fancyplain
\let\ps@startpage\ps@fancyplain
\makeatother
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[draft,wd,letterpaper]{isov2}
\let\ifpdf\relax 

% Header and Footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\uppercase{ISO/IEEE 11073-10201:2013(E)}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\tiny{\uppercase{Health informatics --- Point-of-care medical device communication}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\uppercase{Part 10201: Domain information model}}
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{Copyright \textcopyright $\;$ 2013 ISO/IEEE. All rights reserved.}
%\fancyfoot[CO,RE]{To: Dean A. Smith}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\makeatletter
\let\ps@headings\ps@fancyplain
\let\ps@isotitlehead\ps@fancyplain
\let\ps@startpage\ps@fancyplain
\makeatother

\standard{ISO/IEEE 11073-10201}
\yearofedition{2013}
\languageofedition{(E)}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}     % ToC includes ssclauses and above

\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\clause{Before Title}
Words before Title
\title{Example Document}{}{}

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\clause{Hello}\lipsum
\sclause{Little}\lipsum
\clause{Second}\lipsum

\end{document}
```